# fetch_assoc not returning all columns data from mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code and i get the data for columns except the flag_images and flag_created.
the rows flag_images contain integer 0 but when i try to echo them i get noting.
what might be the issue?
please help

```
$product = [];
        $row_count++;
        // echo "\r\n [".$row_count."] " . $data[0] . " <=======\r\n";
        $amazon_db = sprintf("select `ratings`,`manufacturer`,`reviews`,`old_price`,`stock`,`asin`,`product_name`,`price`,`description`,`zap_price`,`product_link`,`shipping_o_price`,`images`,`flag_images`,`flag_created` from `amazon-crawler` WHERE `asin` ='%s' limit 0,1", $data[0]);
        $amazon_result = $amazon_conn->query($amazon_db);
        if (@$amazon_result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $amazon_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $product['asin'] = $row['asin'];
                $product['manufacturer'] = $row['manufacturer'];
                $product['price'] = $row['price'];
                $product['zap_link_price'] = $row['zap_price'];
                $product['product_link'] = $row['product_link'];
                $product['shipping_o_price'] = $row['shipping_o_price'];
                $product['images'] = $row['images'];
                **$product['flag_images'] = $row['flag_images'];
                $product['flag_created'] = $row['flag_created'];**
                echo $product['flag_created'];
                echo $product['flag_images'];
                $product['stock'] = $row['stock'];
                $product['amazon_ratings'] = $row['ratings'];
```

Comment: I think you're confusing rows with columns.

Comment: yes i mean columns. i get all columns except the two

Comment: What is the datatype of these columns? What does `var_dump($product['flag_images'])` show?

Comment: `var_dump($row)`, see the keys and values there.

Comment: I suspect it's being returned as a boolean, not integer. Use `intval($row['flag_images'])`

Comment: var dump returns
  ["flag_images"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["flag_created"]=>
  string(1) "0"

Comment: intval($row['flag_images']) seems to solve it!!!